# Room Proguard - re-obfuscating old database members

Tags: android, android-room, proguard

I have a major production bug!
Without notice I uploaded a room version without the Proguard rules:
-keepclassmembers class mypackagename.models.*{*;}
-keepnames class mypackagename.models.*{*;}

So my data base look something like this:
[{"a":787.0,"b":615.0,"c":250.0,"d":false},{"a":1077.0,"b":386.0,"c":402.0,"d":false},{"a":484.0,"b":789.0,"c":267.0,"d":false},{"a":125.0,"b":10.0,"c":500.0,"d":false},{"a":493.0,"b":1185.0,"c":319.0,"d":false}]

But in my new version I Added the new rules and now the db look something likee
this:

[{"name":787.0,"size":615.0,"point":250.0,"isFound":false},{"name":1077.0,"size":386.0,"point":402.0,"isFound":false},{"name":484.0,"size":789.0,"point":267.0,"isFound":false},{"name":125.0,"size":10.0,"point":500.0,"isFound":false},{"name":493.0,"b":1185.0,"point":319.0,"isFound":false}]

When a user from a previous version migrate to the current version - the app simply don't work.

Is there a way that I can migrate the db with the new profound rules?
Or alternately, is there a way to change the proguard rules in runtime?

Thanks in advance I hope my question is clear.

Comment: did you find any solutions? I would like to know how you solved this issue. I will appreciated it if you could leave your solution.

Comment: I don't know what the author did but the only solution I can think of is to write a migration for the DB.
1. create new tables with valid names
2. migrate the old data using the map file that was created when obfuscating the app
3. drop obfuscated tables

Comment: Hi, I don't remember what i did.. i think i ended up upload an update to the app that delete the db...